# Amount locked in vesting

Tags: polkadot-js

How do I get the amount locked in vesting using [this](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#vestingaccountid32-optionvecpalletvestingvestinginfo) method.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as `Solution` if it solved your problem. This helps the community to find answers quickly.

Answer (score 4):

The function return an `Option<Vec<PalletVestingVestingInfo>>` and therefore needs to be unwrapped. It is explained [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.basics/#working-with-optiontype).
The following snipped prints the vesting info for a specific account on Polkadot.

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

// Put your address here
const addr = '...';
const response = await api.query.vesting.vesting(addr)

response.unwrapOrDefault().forEach(vesting =>
    console.log(`Address ${addr} has ${vesting.locked} locked since starting block ${vesting.startingBlock} and unlocking ${vesting.perBlock} per block.`)
);
```

This will print:
`Address ... has ... locked since starting block ... and unlocking ... per block.`